# Is the flash on a Nikon D5600 supposed to pop up and fire automatically, if so what camera settings to achieve this

Tags: nikon, popup-flash

Pretty much as title.  I have just acquired a Nikon D5600 and had gained the impression from somewhere that the onboard flash is supposed to pop up and fire automatically if light levels are too low.  But I have tried various different camera settings in very poor light, even total darkness, and haven't been able to make this happen.  If this is supposed to happen, what camera settings will achieve this?

Comment: There is a small button just below the flash that makes it pop up, which will fire the flash when you hit the trigger. Otherwise I think it fires usually only with Auto mode

Comment: Yes, thanks, I'd got that far.  My problem seems to have been, although I thought I'd tried them all, that I was using the wrong modes.  Incidentally, it is in covered in the User Guide, but it's in the specifications section, which is why I didn't find it initially by eye - I only found it when I had an electronic copy I could search.

Comment: @ssn - That is in fact the correct answer. If you write it as such, then it could be accepted by the OP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing much about it in the [User Guide](http://download.nikonimglib.com/archive3/J7u3b009znQG03OkuJp979kO8896/D5600UM_EU(En)04.pdf) supplied with the camera, but it's there in the [D5600 Reference Manual](http://download.nikonimglib.com/archive3/T2D6s009HCPw03w5wYS97chunQ10/D5600RM_(En)04.pdf), printed page 101, pdf page counter 127.  This lists the modes for which the flash pops up automatically, and, using the Auto mode (defined by the Auto/Camera icon), I've checked that it works as expected, which hitherto I had not been able to do.

Answer (score 3):

Only in auto mode will the flash automatically pop up. If you are in the manual type modes, you have to hit the flash button on the top left side of the camera to pop the flash up.